# How do I un-mount a drive in Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I successfully mounted a network drive in the Windows Subsystem for Linux (Ubuntu).

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/t
sudo mount -t drvfs T: /mnt/t
```

After exiting bash, and coming back, I still see the `/mnt/t` directory, but it is empty. How do I un-mount this drive?

I have tried `sudo umount /mnt/t` but it says this each time:

`umount: /mnt/t/: not mounted`

How do I un-mount it?

Comment: If it is not mounted then run `sudo rmdir /mnt/t`

Comment: @DavidPostill Suave Dave, suave.  Savin' the world 1 jabe at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### After exiting bash, and coming back, I still see the /mnt/t directory, but it is empty

If it is not mounted then run `sudo rmdir /mnt/t`

Answer (score 3):

Unmount using:

`sudo umount /mnt/t`

*Note it's **umount** and not unmount.

Then remove the directory using:

`sudo rmdir /mnt/t`